# I can't figure out why I'm getting this error in rails app: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Ok I've been trying to figure this out for awhile... I wan´t to render a partial in the `views/users/show.html.erb`

This is the form code in the partial that I want rendered

```
<%= form_for @addon, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal center"} do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :addon_1, "1.Addon:", class: "col-md-4 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <%= f.text_field :addon_1, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :addon_2, "2.Addon:", class: "col-md-4 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <%= f.text_field :addon_2, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :addon_3, "3.Addon:", class: "col-md-4 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <%= f.text_field :addon_3, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>
```

I have an `addon.rb` model and `user.rb`model

this is the `addon.rb` model

```
class Addon < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

And this is the `user.rb`model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :addons
end
```

And in the `users_controller.rb` I have, this in the `show`action

```
def show
  #@addon = current_user.addons.build
   @addons = current_user.addons
end
```

I've tried to both use `@addons` and `@addon` it both gives errors.

If I use `@addons` rails gives back this error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

and if I try to use `@addon` rails gives back this error :`unknown attribute 'user_id' for Addon`

Am I missing something here, I can't see why this shouldn't work, can anyone please advise.

Comment: There is a lot of unrelated code (routes, probably AddonsController). Can you remove this? Also please provide full stack trace for the `user_id` missing case.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not logged in, so there is no `current_user` & `@addon`.

Comment: I'm logged in as user with user_id: 18, which makes  me the current_user at the moment I am using the app.